# When use clicktoflash, how to show other flashs in a webview based on Safari?

Tags: cocoa, safari

Now I develop a program with a webview showing flash. but I found that when I installed clickToFlash , the webview not to show the flash. I think that when webview load , the safari will check the MIMETYPE , and clickToFlash's MIMETYPE will first chek by safari , so the clicktoflash will handle my falsh , but it didn't have methods to do this. What I want to know is in clicktoflash how to disable the MIMETYPE in info.plist for a while when I show swf in my webview. and I researched the code of clicktoflash , I found it can change the mimetype from "application/x-shockwave-flash" to "application/futuresplash", but swf didn't show again,why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your app opt out of clicktoflash. The process is described at the bottom of http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/

"Include a key named "ClickToFlashOptOut" in your app's Info.plist file, set its value to 'YES', and your app will automatically be whitelisted by ClickToFlash."

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of installing ClickToFlash is to stop Flash content from loading. If you have a problem with this then don't install it.

Comment: When installed ClickToFlash , other showing flash webview didn't work? and ClickToflash have not a method to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you want to do, but you can add sites to a whitelist in the ClickToFlash settings.